# month level roll up in R in day level

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is in a daily level, and I am trying to create a flag for the rows where monthly aggregation has no value.

for example,

- if a contract has a monthly subtotal of budget_case > 0 and actual_case > 0 then put contract_flag value as 1. otherwise, show 0 for the flag.

how would you code so that contract_flag evaluates this?

```
        date  contract  budget_case  actual_case   contract_flag 
1  2017-01-01   F123         200        100              1     
2  2017-01-02   F123         200        100              1     
3  2017-01-03   F123         200        100              1     
4  2017-01-04   F123         200        100              1     
5  2017-01-05   F123         200        100              1     
6  2017-01-06   F123         200        100              1     
7  2017-01-29   F123         200        100              1     
8  2017-01-30   F123         200        100              1     
9  2017-01-01   K456         0          0                0     
10 2017-01-02   K456         0          0                0    
11 2017-01-03   K456         0          0                0     
12 2017-01-04   K456         0          0                0     
13 2017-01-05   K456         0          0                0   
14 2017-01-06   K456         0          0                0     
15 2017-01-29   K456         0          0                0     
16 2017-01-30   K456         0          0                0
```

Comment: These look like daily contracts instead of monthly. Do you mean to flag every row where `budget_case > 0` and `actual_case > 0` or you want to group_by month? Also, your data only has one month. Can you provide data with more months so we know what your expected output looks like with more months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `format.Date` to extract year and month and use that as a `group_by` variable:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Month = format.Date(date, format="%Y-%m")) %>%
  mutate(contract_flag = ifelse(sum(budget_case) > 0 & sum(actual_case) > 0, 1, 0))
```

or with `case_when`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Month = format.Date(date, format="%Y-%m")) %>%
  mutate(contract_flag = case_when(sum(budget_case) > 0 & sum(actual_case) > 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   Month [3]
   date       contract budget_case actual_case contract_flag Month  
   <chr>      <chr>          <int>       <int>         <dbl> <chr>  
 1 2017-01-01 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 2 2017-01-02 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 3 2017-01-03 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 4 2017-01-04 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 5 2017-01-05 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 6 2017-01-06 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 7 2017-01-29 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 8 2017-01-30 F123             200         100             1 2017-01
 9 2017-01-01 K456               0           0             1 2017-01
10 2017-01-02 K456               0           0             1 2017-01
11 2017-01-03 K456               0           0             1 2017-01
12 2017-01-04 K456               0           0             1 2017-01
13 2017-01-05 K456               0           0             1 2017-01
14 2017-02-06 K456               0         100             1 2017-02
15 2017-02-28 K456             200           0             1 2017-02
16 2017-03-30 K456               0           0             0 2017-03
```

**Data** (Modified the date column for more month examples):

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", 
"2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-06", "2017-01-29", "2017-01-30", 
"2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", 
"2017-02-06", "2017-02-28", "2017-03-30"), contract = c("F123", 
"F123", "F123", "F123", "F123", "F123", "F123", "F123", "K456", 
"K456", "K456", "K456", "K456", "K456", "K456", "K456"), budget_case = c(200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 200L, 0L), actual_case = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 0L), contract_flag = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("date", 
"contract", "budget_case", "actual_case", "contract_flag"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I didn't know the group by statement would not remove rows at a lower granularity.